# failed to open stream: Permission denied in

Tags: php, login, webforms

Estoy aprendiendo a hacer que un formulario con php, guarde los archivos enviados en un **.txt** pero estoy teniendo problemas para hacerlo, me indica que no tengo el permiso para hacerlo.

Estos son los errores que me arroja, agradecería mucho si me pudieran dar una mano.

Lo estoy desarrollando de forma local con XAMPP.

**"Warning: fopen(datos/vargas.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PRUEBA/validar.php on line 16
"**

**"Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PRUEBA/validar.php on line 17"**

```
    index.php

    <form method="post" action="validar.php">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="nombre">nombre</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txtNombre" name="txtNombre"><label></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label for="apellido">apellido</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txtApellido" name="txtApellido"><label></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label for="Telefono">telefono</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txtTelefono" name="txtTelefono"><label></td>
            </tr>      
            <tr>
                <td><button type="submit">enviar</button></td>
            </tr>   
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

```
validar.php

<?php
x$nombre = $_POST["txtNombre"];
$apellido = $_POST["txtApellido"];
$telefono = $_POST["txtTelefono"];

$contenido="
Nombre: $nombre
Apellido: $apellido
Telefono: $telefono
";

$archivo=fopen("datos/$apellido.txt","w");
fwrite($archivo, $contenido);
?>
```

Comment: que dice el error???

Comment: Verifique primero que el usuario con el que se ejecuta el runtime de php en el sistema operativo (server o local) tiene permisos (de sistema operativo) para accesar el archivo

Answer (score 0):

El error se presenta debido a que no existe la carpeta llamada datos en la cual quieres crear el archivo $apellido.txt y por lo tanto, no puede escribirlo.
Primeor deberías verificar si la carpeta existe y de lo contrario crearla, un ejempo sería agregar esta validación antes de utilziar fopen:

```
if (!file_exists('datos/')) {
   mkdir('datos', 0755, true);
}
```

Con esto el problema debería de resolverse.